# PHP extract specific from url <a id=id class=class href=www.link.com?_pgn=

Tags: php, hyperlink, href, extract

the html link is:

```
 <a title="Next page of results" class="sprBtnSRP1 enabled" href="http://www.link.com/page.html?thisisthelink&_pgn=2&_al=25&at=tc"><i>Next</i><b class="sprBtnSRP1"></b></a>
```

the php is:

```
function NextLink($url){
        $html= WGET($url);
        $urlpattern1 = '/Next"><a[^>]+pgn=([^"]+)/i';
        preg_match_all($urlpattern1, $html, $matches1);
        $nextlink='http://www.link.com/page.html?thisisthelink&_pgn=';
         foreach ($matches1[1] as $u) {
            $nextlink = $nextlink.$u;
         }
        return $nextlink;
    }
```

## ===============

is not working anymore, what i need is in PHP the $nexlink.$u to become `http://www.link.com/page.html?thisisthelink&_pgn=2&_al=25&at=tc`

THE PROBLEM IS $urlpattern1

thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern :

```
$urlpattern1 = '/<a\s+.*?href=".*?_pgn=(.*?)".*?>/i';
```

**Edit :**

If only that link you want then you can use the title (or other parameter) as a hint, try this pattern :

```
$urlpattern1 = '/<a\s+.*?title="Next page of results"\s+.*?href=".*?\_pgn=(.*?)".*?>/i';
```

Comment: the problem is that the _pgn= has to be extracted from a specific url : `<a title="Next page of results" class="sprBtnSRP1 enabled" href="http://www.link.com/page.html?thisisthelink&_pgn=2&_al=25&at=tc"><i>Next</i><b class="sprBtnSRP1"></b></a>` cause on the html page I have a lot of links and this specified link has to be used i th pattern... Please excuse my english